# How to avoid a new line when user presses ENTER key in a WPF TextBox with AccptsReturn="True"

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a text editing application in WPF C#, in which I need to add a new line when the user presses the CTRL + ENTER combination and perform another operation when the user presses the ENTER key. I tried using the following code in the Keydown event, but the line is added when ENTER is pressed and not added when CTRL + ENTER is pressed. Any help is most welcome. Thanks.

```
    private void rtbText_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
        {
            switch (e.Key)
            {
                case Key.Enter: break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                btnFormat_Click(this, null);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using PreviewKeydown event. When we detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> we add a new line to the text and move the caret to the end.

```
private void rtbText_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
        {
            switch (e.Key)
            {
                case Key.Enter:
                TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
                t.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                t.CaretIndex = t.Text.Length - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
            btnFormat_Click(this, null);
            e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
}
```